# Parameter in the message resource properties file of struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, struts-html

I am using the html:image tag to include images in the jsp. the image location is specified in the message resource properties file of struts. the paths are defined as 
../../images/image1.gid previously. now the context is changing due to some reason, so the images are not being loaded. how do i access the context path in the message resource file? i tried key={0}/images/image1.gif, but this works only for the bean:message as it contains arg0 attribute. but how i do for the image? any round about way?

PS: `<img src=<bean:message arg0="<%=request.getContextPath()%>" key="image1"/>>` works. but i cant change in 100s of jsp files which uses html:image.

thanks
V

Answer (score 0):

> but i cant change in 100s of jsp files which uses html:image.

Use a text editor with *Find & Replace in All Open Files* facility, like [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net).